# Yii ajax loads whole page instead of my output

Tags: ajax, yii

I have a problem in YII with ajax.
I used [this link](http://docs.mirocow.com/doku.php?id=yii%3adependies-select-examle2) as exaple to test ajax in my project with depended drop-down lists.

Form code (protected/views/game/_form.php):

```
<?php 
    echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'season_id', Season::getSeasonsList(), array(
        'ajax' => array(
            'type'=>'POST',
            CController::createUrl('Game/selectGameStages'),
            'update'=>'#Game_season_game_stage'
            )
        )
    ); 
?>
```

Controller code (protected/Controller/GameController.php):

```
public function actionSelectGameStages()
{
    echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value'=>'1'), 'Some output 1', true);        
    echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value'=>'2'), 'Some output 2', true);        
    echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value'=>'3'), 'Some output 3', true);        
}
```

Ajax is working, but with debugger if founded that code, putted in my Game_season_game_stage select is the html code of the whole page of my site, like as

```
<select name="Game[season_game_stage] id="Game_season_game_stage">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    ...
    <div class="container" id="page">...</div>
```

Please help to understand why whole code of page loaded instead of code from my selectGameStages function?
Yii version is 1.14.
Sorry for my English. Thx.

Comment: please add the code which you want to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all answers! I found solution.

in protected/views/game/_form.php I missed the 'url' key and renamed game/selectGameStages

```
<?php 
    echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'season_id', Season::getSeasonsList(), array(
        'ajax' => array(
            'type'=>'POST',
            'url' => CController::createUrl('game/selectGameStages'),
            'update'=>'#Game_season_game_stage'
            )
        )
    ); 
?>
```

after that I updated controller code (protected/Controller/GameController.php) with this code

```
public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view', 'selectGameStages'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Simply exit after the output.

```
public function actionSelectGameStages()
{
    // Do stuff
    ...

    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why noy use dropDownList and directly in the view?

es.

```
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('listname', $select, 
              array('M' => 'Male', 'F' => 'Female'),
              array('empty' => '(Select a gender)'));
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/48/by-example-chtml/#hh5

Comment: I need to generate options from other table dependent by the selected value from first dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

Your whole page is loading because of your layout,

in your controller check if this call, is an ajax call, change your layout to some layout without those tags, or better create a layout for your ajax calls,

```
if($this->getIsAjaxRequest())
      $this->layout = '//ajax'; // ajax layout
```